# I get BrokenPipeError on convert_from_bytes pdf2image python3

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

Please help, this script works perfectly on OSX, but don't work on windows10. (but I need)... This program will extract the conver page as .png, but it gives BrokenPipeError

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
import sys
import os

def get_cover(input_file, ext):
    inp = PdfFileReader(input_file+ext, "rb")
    page = inp.getPage(0)

    wrt = PdfFileWriter()
    wrt.addPage(page)

    r = io.BytesIO()
    wrt.write(r)

    images = convert_from_bytes(r.getvalue())
    images[0].save(input_file+".png")
    print("Done, your cover photo has been saved as {}.".format(input_file+".png"))
    r.close()

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    get_cover(*os.path.splitext(input_file))
else:
    for f in os.listdir():
        f = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f[1]==".pdf":
            print("Processing {}{}".format(*f))
            get_cover(*f)
```

The error message:

```
PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PDF_cover_extractor.py", line 30, in <module>
    get_cover(*f)
  File "PDF_cover_extractor.py", line 17, in get_cover
    images = convert_from_bytes(r.getvalue())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 55, in convert_from_bytes
    proc.stdin.write(pdf_file)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```